# Calculation of daily dividends from total return index data

Tags: dividends, asset-returns

I have a question regarding the inclusion of dividend payments in total return indices, but I have no background in finance, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out - any help is highly appreciated!

Let's assume that I have two time series of equal length for a stock index like the S&P 500, one as a total return index and one as a price index, and I would like to calculate the time series of daily dividend payments from these two index time series, how would I go about doing this?

Is this even possible or does it make sense? I am interested in comparing data on monthly dividend payments of an index, which seem a bit strange to me, with data that I can calculate directly from index data itself and get a more accurate picture of the daily dividend dynamics over the course of several years.

Thank you!

Comment: I do this on a monthly basis (using the end of month values of ^SPX and ^SP500TR from Yahoo). I find that the monthly data is somewhat jumpy and it takes 3 or 4 successive months averaged together to get a reliable estimate of the annualized dividend rate. I think daily data would be far too erratic, depending more on the random luck of what companies happen to be paying dividends today than on the underlying dividend paying behavior of US firms.